# Remove SoftDeletingScope as global scope

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am trying to remove the `SoftDeletingScope` as a global scope for a specific user role. So it should somehow look like this:

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    if (Auth::check()) {
        // CPOs can see deleted users
        if (Auth::user()->hasRole('cpo')) {
            static::addGlobalScope('user-cpo-deleted', function(Builder $builder) {
                // 1
                $builder->withoutGlobalScope(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingScope::class);
                // 2
                $builder->withoutGlobalScopes();
                // 3
                $builder->withTrashed();
                // 4
                $builder->where('id', '>=', 1);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I tried solution 1-3 and, to make sure the method is called at all, 4. I logged the SQL queries and saw that 4 was called, but not the 3 before (to be precise, the methods did not remove the `users.deleted_at is null` part). I tried them separately and all together.

I know I can do something like this `$users = User::withTrashed()->get();`, which works, but that would be not entirely safe, because I would have to find every location where users could be queried and wrap that in an if statement.

Comment: I know it sound stupid, but can you try to chain the calls like `$builder->method()->method() etc`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment but the solution of @devk worked;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of easier solution than override `bootSoftDeletes()` from SoftDeletes trait with something like this:

```
public static function bootSoftDeletes()
{
    if (!Auth::check() || !Auth::user()->hasRole('cpo')) {
        static::addGlobalScope(new SoftDeletingScope);
    }
}
```

Adding and removing global scopes on the fly yields some wierd behaviour sometimes :/

Comment: That's easy enough for me. I thought nothing good can come out of it if you remove all global scopes while adding one.

Answer (score 0):

This solution removes the scope based on a condition. Prevents call to undefined method errors which I got using the accepted answer.

```php
<?php namespace App\Scopes;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Scope;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingScope;

/**
 * Class UserScope
 *
 * @package App\Scopes
 */
class UserScope implements Scope
{
    /**
     * @param Builder $builder
     * @param Model   $model
     */
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        if (optional(auth()->user())->is_admin) $builder->withoutGlobalScope(SoftDeletingScope::class);
    }
}
```

In order for this to work, I had to make sure the scope was added before calling the models parent boot method.